# Laptop fan runs continuously even when not using the application

Tags: performance

My laptop fan runs continuously even when not using the application. CPU fan speed is 2300 RPM. Is that normal? This is my first time using elementary OS.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `top` command in Terminal and check the %CPU column.

Comment: Good suggestion. I sometimes have one or more `-bash` commands eating up resources. After killing them, CPU usage (and thus fan speeds) return to normal.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. My CPU is about 40%. When I use windows fans will turn slower when the machine is not working. But in the elementary os, it always rotates at a high speed. Does windows have BIOS, elementary not?

Comment: I think it's some software you installed that keeps running in the backgraound after you close it. That's why I suggested the `top` command to see which app is consuming CPU.

Answer (score 0):

The  **top**  command is what was needed. THX alot. 
Ad first I tried to find out with gnome system monitor..it showed me 0% CPU usage.
**top command**

> identified high CPU usage of **packgagekitd**

, which is an update lookup and for the reason my fans where spinning full time.
Just in case you experience the same issue..after using **top**, type:

> sudo killall -KILL packagekitd

and quite time is back again.BTW, I'm new to Elementary Os..I started with Juno..